# executeScript not working if frameId included

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Does Microsoft Edge support `executeScript` with `frameId` yet?

If I do:

```
 browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { frameId:0, code:'alert("wha")' })
```

If I include `frameId` in it, it causes error of this:

> Unhandled promise rejection Error: Invalid value for argument 2. Property 'frameId': Unexpected property.

I get frameId's with webNavigation.getAllFrames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`Supported APIs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis#tabs),

> Executing script in a specific frame is not yet supported.

Comment: Thanks Hibara this was exactly the page I was looking for. Thanks for the link!